# Automatically copy row to another workbook/worksheet when specific cell in the row is updated

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched online and couldn't find a code to do what I'm looking to do and I hit a tumbling block..

We're currently looking to implement a CRM-like reporting system for our reps in excel.  Our reps would fill out customer data in a row and just update the relevant cells when the account status changes one way or another.

The report is all built and works but we're lacking the account history part so what we're looking to do, is to copy the whole row in a new row to a different sheet or workbook any time the data in column I is updated for a row so there's a history of all relevant changes kept automatically on a separate sheet or worksheet.

I've searched and looked online at different codes and the tracking changes option but could not find a code that would automatically copy only the whole relevant row on update and we really need the whole row to be copied for the data to remain meaningful to us so track changes doesn't work for our needs.  We'd also require for these steps to happen without action from our users.

Any help on how this could be accomplished would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen anything regarding `Worksheet_Change()`? Do some searches for that, and you should find stuff.  Generally, `Sub Worksheet_Change(byVal Target as Range) // If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then ...`  What have you tried? What have you searched for, but come up with nothing on?

Comment: I've added the excel-vba tags to your post, as vba is the only practical way to do this.

Comment: For performance reasons, you will probably need to hold the second (target) workbook open continuously.

Comment: Can you use a real database? Even Access would work. Then this could function like a proper application without a good deal of the headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [WorksheetChangeEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) to detect when something has been changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' do stuff
End Sub
```

Put the above code into the worksheet object (double click on the worksheet in the code editor).

Use [Application.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835030.aspx) to narrow down what has been changed. For instance if you're only interested in cells I1 to I10000:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("I1:I1000")) Is Nothing Then
     ' do stuff
End If

End Sub
```

Then copy the required row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("I1:I10000")) Is Nothing Then

    Rows(Target.Row).copy
    ' paste it where you want it

End If

End Sub
```

Target is the range for the affected cell. Of course the user can affect more than one cell at once e.g. by autofilling, so you may need to put some additional logic e.g if Target.Rows.Count > 1, but you get the idea.